# Matlab loop functions over different cells

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, loops

Edited: May 8. Thanks for the comments below.

I have a set of data on firms and years. Each firm's data are stored in a cell array. I need to run a function `firm` to estimate a vector for each firm. There are thousands of firm. It went well if I write the function specially for one firm, but I don't know how to apply the function to each array cell at one time.

My function for a single cell is (some calculation inside is simplified):

```
function obj=firm(data,s)
a=data(:,1);
b=data(:,2);
obj=f(a,b,s); 
%obj is a function of a,b and s to estimate
end
```

Then when I used `fminsearch` as following, it worked well:
`[mix, mifval]=fminsearch(@(s) firm(data{1,1},s),zeros(1,n))`

But now considering applying it for thousands of firms (thousands of cells). I wrote a loop:

```
function obj=firm(data,s)
n=size(data,2);    
 for i=1:n
a=data{1,i}(:,1);
b=data{1,i}(:,2);
 % here I want i to be a loop from 1 to n.
obj=f(a,b,s{1,i}); 
 % Obj is a function of a, b and the s I focus on. 
 end
end
```

And then I call: 
`[mix, mifval]=fminsearch(@(s) whole(supdata,supitem,s),a)
%a is the initial value of s, a matrix of n*12`

The mix returned is exactly n*12, but mifval is only a scalar, which should be a n*1 vector returning the minimal value of `obj`.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: so you want a loop, or you want to avoid the loop? to avoid the loop, consider `cellfun`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html

Comment: @scmg thanks for the info about cellfun. Loop is acceptable as long as it solves my problem. I like cellfun. But I am not sure whether I can use it with global search, I need a global minimum of the obj function for each cell.

Comment: i'm not sure if they could be used together since i'm noob by `fminsearch`, but when `cellfun` is used with matlab built-in functions, it's much faster than for-loop.

Comment: You should ask one question at a time. Your question about allocating cell arrays is a fine one, but should be asked on it's own without all of the optimization details.

Comment: What is the function `f`? What is the type/class of `obj` is a cell array or a numeric array? Are you expecting `fminsearch` to solve multiple simultaneous optimization problems – one each for for each element in `s{1,:}`?

Comment: @horchler The function `f` is  very complicated, with a cumulative value for each time and sum all the absolute values over time over s. About 10 lines of code. I did not put it here in case it distract you. But it still did... "

Comment: @horchler "What is the type/class of obj" --both cell array or numeric array are fine. But now neither works. Yes this is the reduced version of the other question you kindly edited. This one is easier, with involving global search. But still it didn't work.