# Matlab: How to use cellfun when using "createOptimProblem"?

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimum, cell-array

I would like to find global minima using an objective function I defined.

The code I used is:

```
opts = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','interior-point');
gs = GlobalSearch;
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',a,'objective', @(s) obj(supdata,s),'options',opts);
[xg, fg, exitflag, output, solutions ]=run(gs, problem)
```

The problem is that `supdata` is for a specific firm, and I need to get the optimal result for each firm (there are thousands of them). I want to apply this code using a big data input (which I already have, in a cell array, with each cell being a specific firm), and the output `xg` `fg`... are also varies among firms.

I was hoping to use a loop inside the function `obj`, but people here suggested that I to change my function to use `cellfun`: see [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091633/matlab-loop-functions-over-different-cells?noredirect=1#comment48315118_30091633). But I don't know how to incorporate it into `globalsearch`. It is more complicated than just calling the solver `fmincon`.

Comment: `cellfun` doesn't avoid the loop, it just hides it from you in a convenient one-line function, which will sometimes be faster, but is often slower, than a simple `for`. If anything, it looks like you need to vectorize your functions. Get it working with what you know and don't prematurely optimize. This question is unclear and not specific enough for anyone to provide a specific answer. I'm also not sure that its sufficiently different from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30091633/2278029), which is also not completely clear either.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for editing!!! Let me see how I can specify it.